# SQL query has to return all data, not only existing data

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I am not a master in queries so I need some help...
I got the following query:

```
SELECT u.id, device_id, profit
  FROM device d
  JOIN user u ON d.user_id = u.id 
  WHERE day = '2017-12-20' and u.id= '22'
```

Now this returns

```
--------------------------------------------------
| u.id| device_id   |profit                      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 22  |1            |200                         |
--------------------------------------------------
| 22  |2            |600                         |
-------------------------------------------------
| 22  |4            |400                         |
--------------------------------------------------
| 22  |5            |650                         |
--------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, a device_id is missing (3), I would want the result to be like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| u.id| device_id   |profit                      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 22  |1            |200                         |
--------------------------------------------------
| 22  |2            |600                         |
-------------------------------------------------
| 22  |3            |0 (or null)                 |
-------------------------------------------------
| 22  |4            |400                         |
--------------------------------------------------
| 22  |5            |650                         |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Cause when I run

```
SELECT DISTINCT device_id
FROM device
```

I get

```
---------------
|device_id    |
---------------
|1            |
---------------
|2            |
---------------
|3            |
---------------
|4            |
---------------
|5            |
---------------
```

And basically what I want is to display every device on the user, no matter if that user has a profit on that device or not, I was thinking about a JOIN on the same table, is that possible in some way?

**EDIT**

The 'user' table looks like this:

```
------------
|id | name |
------------
```

And the 'device' table like this:

```
-------------------------------
|user_id | device_id | profit |
-------------------------------
```

Comment: Where is `day` stored?

Comment: `day` is also stored in the `device` table

Comment: Please show your table definitions.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT u.id, device_id, profit
FROM device d
LEFT JOIN user u ON d.user_id = u.id 
WHERE d.day = '2017-12-20' and d.user_id = '22'
```

If this doesn't return `3` then it must be that 1 of the 2 filters on the device table are excluding it.

Comment: You are right, in my case this solution doesn't work because device `3` does not exist on the user with id `22`, but I still want to try to include device 3 without any profit (profit = null or 0)

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for `LEFT JOIN` in place of `JOIN`.  You probably want...

```
SELECT u.id, device_id, profit
  FROM user u
  LEFT JOIN device d ON d.user_id = u.id 
 WHERE day = '2017-12-20' and u.id= '22'
```

or maybe

```
SELECT u.id, device_id, profit
  FROM device d
 RIGHT JOIN user u ON d.user_id = u.id 
 WHERE day = '2017-12-20' and u.id= '22'
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately...I think the problem is that I have 5 devices but when I left join I only get the devices the user has any profit from (so not device with id 3).

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I think you want:

```
SELECT u.id, d.device_id, d.profit
FROM user u LEFT JOIN
     device d
     ON d.user_id = u.id AND d.day = '2017-12-20'
WHERE u.id = 22;
```

It is a little hard to say exactly, because you don't specify what the tables look like.

EDIT:

The above will return `NULL` device ids.  So, if the column assignments are correct, then this simpler query will work:

```
SELECT 22 as id, d.device_id,
       (CASE WHEN d.user_id = 22 AND d.day = '2017-12-20' THEN d.profit END) as profit
FROM device d;
```

Comment: Same as above, left join still return only devices which user has a profit from, any way to include the last one? I also added my table structure to the question if you want to have a look at that

Comment: @peaceduck . .  . Did you try the second query.